# How to capture multiple keyboard input in python

Tags: python, events, asynchronous, keyboard

If I have multiple keyboards plugged into a computer, how would I capture both the keyboard and the key pressed asynchronously using python 2.7? Is there a package or method that will allow operating system independence?

Comment: visit http://www.thelinuxdaily.com/2010/05/grab-raw-keyboard-input-from-event-device-node-devinputevent/

Comment: which os do you want this for? You're unlikely to find existing packages. You're essentially trying to make a key logger.

Comment: Asking on python , create a `symlink` and read as buffer.

Comment: I would like an os independent solution if possible.